# Properly parsing through an XML file from an HTTP request

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, .net-4.8

I am using Windows Forms .NET Framework and HTTPClient for web requests. I'm able so successfully get the response message. I'm now wanting to grab a specific attribute named 'special-price' from the 'item' elements. I only care about the first instance of a 'price-attribute' in an element. The following is a snippet of the code that is returning the error.

```
HttpResponseMessage request = await client.GetAsync($"url");
string result = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(result);
var query = from item in xDocument.Element("inv-balance").Elements("item")
            select item.Attribute("special-price");
var answer = query.First();
rtxtResult.Text = answer.ToString();`
```

The error I keep getting is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I'm still relatively new to C# and this is the first major roadblock that I haven't been able to get past. Thank you.

Comment: Post a redacted meaningful section of the XML -- Why do you have `... await client.GetAsync()` and then `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`? Don't do that, await `ReadAsStringAsync()` as you're awaiting `GetAsync()`

Comment: How exactly does the XML look like?

Comment: if you break it down step by step are you able to get just the `inv-balance` elements on their own, if that returns null then the next one will fail. it could be malformed XML or it could be namespacing issues. missing optional fiels such as item, or special-price, etc

Comment: Any chance you really wanted `xDocument.Root.Element("inv-balance")`?  `xDocument.Element("inv-balance")` looks for a **root element** `<inv-balance>` whereas `xDocument.Root.Element("inv-balance")` looks for a **child of the root element** of that name.  Mistaking the `XDocument` for the root element is a common mistake to make.  If not, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve],specifically simplified XML (with sensitive information redacted if necessary) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You probably have a namespace issue.  If the Element is not found than the select "special-price will give an your exception.  Also query.First() will give the exception.